# how can i create more buttons in landscape than exist in portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout

Im building a calculator app with  friend and when i was starting the landscape layout i realized that the app would crash immediately on launch after the oncreate method because it was looking in the portrait xml fil, i commented out the portion of the method that made up the new buttons and now it runs, but i cant use the new buttons that i declared in the landscape xml file.

i dont know how to create them as it is my understanding that the oncreate method is executed once when the app is launched.

How do i create them so that the app wont crash on launch and they can still be used?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create a qualifier. It will then duplicate your xml so you can redesign your landscape mode without messing up portrait mode.

In Eclipse GUI xml editor, switch to landscape and press Create to create a new qualifier.

Here's a link to Google IO's video tutorial [Google IO ADT 2011](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-development-tools.html) which is the best Android tutorial I've ever seen.

Comment: If you're not sure what the qualifier is, see this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty answer,

You could have them in the portrait XML file with the attribute:

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```